# how to filter measurement noise out of a set of data

Tags: regression

I need to find the best way to filter white noise from a set of data  $(x_0,y_0),...,(x_n,y_n)$, $n>1000$, where

$x:\text{ is a time variable}$

$y:\text{ is a physical quantity}$

The noise is coming from the sensor taking the measurements. We know that the noise follows the standard normal probability law (gaussian distribution with and esperence equal to zero $m=0$), but we have no information about the value of the variance ($\sigma$ is unknown).

So to deal with this problem, I taught about doing linear regression, but I don't know what's the best model to use.

In fact, the measurements correspond to the thermographical data of an electrical equipment whether it is operational or quiescent (not operating but confronted to the heat of its environment)

Note that the measurements are not taken with a constant sampling period. for example the value $x_3-x_2$ differs from $x_4-x_3$.

So my question is:
**how to deal with the white noise?**

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what the target decision is or which of, or both of, the two measurements are noisy.  However two methods occur:
1.  Total least squares regression when both series are noisy.
2.  A technique which is used to detect bias in manufacturing is to integrate the dependent variable.  If $z_k = \Sigma_{i=1}^k y_i $ or better $z_k = z_{k-1}+(x_k - x_{k-1})y_k $ then, if $z_k$ is plotted vs $x_k$, the gradient of $z$ indicates the mean value of $x_k$.